# Exception with ObjectInputStream while reading, and reaching the end of the file

Tags: java, file, objectinputstream

I'm doing a schedule book, and I'm saving a .txt all my objects, that works fine, the problem comes when I read them, my program reads , when the end of the file comes, my program doesn't know what to do, I won't put my code because it's a mess right now, but here's my teacher's code, which is the one that I'm using as a template to do mine:

```
try{
  //***Instructions for reading***

  //It creates a streamobject with the file's name and asigned format

  FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("Serializado.txt");

  //It creates an inputobject, so it can represent the object

  ObjectInputStream objIn= new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);

  while (fileIn != null) {

    //with readObject() method,  it extracts the object's content                               

    obInp= (NewAlumno) objIn.readObject(); //Se hace un "cast" a NewAlumno
    System.out.print("Nombre   :" + obInp);
    System.out.print(", Sexo: " + obInp.getSexo());
    System.out.print(", Direccion: "+ obInp.getDireccion());    
    System.out.print(", Promedio: " + obInp.getpromedioPoo());
    System.out.print(", Telefono: " + obInp.getTelefono()+"\n");
  }

  objIn.close();
} catch(Exception e){}  

}
```

As you can see, the catch exception it's empty, so, when i use my teacher's code, it looks like it's working flawlessly, but, i put a println there, and it always prints it. Meaning that something's wrong, and i'm pretty sure that is the

```
while(fileIn != null)
```

bacause Netbeans says that this expression is never null. So i'm guessing that the program doesn't know what to do after he reaches the end of the file... Any sugestions pals? Thanks in an advance!

Here is the exception:

```
java.io.EOFException 
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2‌​577) 
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1315) 
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369) 
  at profegraba.Persistencia.main(Persistencia.java:81)
```

Comment: Put `e.printStackTrace()` in the catch clause and post the results.

Comment: Here:
java.io.EOFException
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2577)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1315)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
 at profegraba.Persistencia.main(Persistencia.java:81)

Comment: @HectorHammett That exception means that you reached the end of the file, but you still ask for more objects to be read. The program can't read any more, because it has reached the end of the file, so the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That exception means that you reached the end of the file, but you still ask for more objects to be read. The program can't read any more, because it has reached the end of the file, so the exception is thrown.

As mentioned before, you should handle your resources more carefully.

You should catch the exception and handle it naturally.

```
ObjectInputStream objIn = null;
try {
    FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("Serializado.txt");
    if (fileIn == null) {
        throw new IOException("Can't find file.");
    }
    objIn= new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);

    while (true) {
        obInp= (NewAlumno) objIn.readObject();
        System.out.print("Nombre   :" + obInp);
        System.out.print(", Sexo: " + obInp.getSexo());
        System.out.print(", Direccion: "+ obInp.getDireccion());    
        System.out.print(", Promedio: " + obInp.getpromedioPoo());
        System.out.print(", Telefono: " + obInp.getTelefono()+"\n");
    }
} catch (EOFException e) {
    // Ignore or do whatever you wanted to signal the end of file.
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStrackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (objIn != null) {
            objIn.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException closeException) {
        closeException.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: There are few correct uses of `available()`, and this isn't one of them. It doesn't tell you whether you've reached the end of the stream: it tells you, maybe, how many bytes are available to be read without blocking. It isn't at all the same thing.

Comment: @EJP Indeed, well thought. I'll fix my answer. Catching the exception is definitely the way to go here.

Comment: Ohh wow, thanks to all of you, it means that i was in the right way. My Professor's code doesn't know what to do with the end of the file, and also i get the idea from afsantos of using the exception to control the program flow, but also i get the explanation from @Duncan Jones. Obviously it feels "Wrong" to use an exception to control your program... but i think it's a very good option due the time. Thanks to all of you guys.

Comment: @HectorHammett Yes, I think it's the only option in your case. I was merely throwing out some thoughts for later consideration if you do this for real.

Comment: Will not the same object be read multiple times when you `objIn.readObject()` like that in a while loop?

Comment: @Lealo Not really. You are reading from the *stream* in a loop. Every time you `readObject`, the stream gives you whatever comes next, until there is nothing more to read.

Comment: Lets say the stream is a straw. And each time it run inside the loop you take another sip. In fact how it works is that the ObjectInputStream take the whole soda in one sip through the straw. So next time you sip (try to read from the the same object twice as I saw it before) - the soda is not there anymore. So unless someone has refilled the glass with other soda there will be an error. I had the misconception that ObjectInputStream copied the content that was in the stream - that the stream was something like a temporary container.

Comment: @Lealo The stream runs out of objects after the first time if, and only if, the source of data contains only one object to read, hence the loop. It keeps track of its *"progress"*. As such, each sip is the amount of soda for a whole object, and as you sip multiple times, you get the objects in order. The exception is raised when you sip one last time but the glass is already empty (end of file).

Comment: Thank you very much I understand now. It reads objects after all, so its better to think the soda as peas or something like that. And each sip is like taking one 1 pea of the pea-container (It is not just data). I think that readObject maybe should be renamed to takeObject though - saying that you read something does not mean that you also remove or delete the content in the same action (the object inside the stream).

Answer (score 2):

The while loop is completely incorrect

```
while (fileIn != null) {
```

If your input file exists, then `fileIn` will always be non-null. You should check if `fileIn` is null immediately after constructing it, however, in case the file path is wrong.

Without the while loop, you are then just reading one object from the stream. Whether this is correct or not, I don't know. However, one should generally know how many objects were written to the stream so that the corresponding number of objects can be read back.

(*You could read until you get an `EOFException`, however I wouldn't personally condone that. I'd suggest you instead stored a container object with a number of sub-objects. An `EOFException` may be thrown for reasons other than because the last object has been read successfully. However, I appreciate you may be forced to code this way to complete your assignment*).

Finally, you need to ensure your input streams are closed, even if an exception occurs. If you are using Java 7, the [try-with-resources construct](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) can make this easier.

Comment: Yeah, the thing is that i'm not able to know how many objects i'll put on the stream, because it's suposed to be variable, and be able to erae files... this is a mess. Thanks man, i'm gonna try to solve this.

Comment: You don't need to know how many objects were written to the stream.

Comment: @Afsantos Yeah, that's what i thought, but i don't know how to tell the program to stop after it reaches the end of the file. This is my teachers code and it's not working correctly... and i'm still looking for a solution, Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

`ObjectInputStream.readObject()` throws `EOFException` when the end of the stream is reached. Your loop should be of the form `while (true)` or `for (;;)` and it should contain a `catch (EOFException exc)` block which breaks out of the loop.

Testing `while (fileIn != null)` is entirely futile.

Comment: Not sure I love the idea of catching an `EOFException` to control program flow. If several objects were being written, I'd advocate wrapping them in a container and writing that. Since ObjectOutputStreams don't place nicely if you append to them, one will almost always know the number of objects to be written at the time of writing.

Comment: @DuncanJones Unfortunately the designers of the API didn't have the benefit of your likes and dislikes when they wrote it. It doesn't always make sense to convolute the code just to please arbitary canons of taste, especially those erected independently of the API design.

Comment: I'm not convinced this is the way the designers of the API intended the stream to be used. The JavaDocs for `ObjectInputStream` don't suggest this as a pattern. They don't even explicitly reference `EOFException` by name. Anyway, it appears we won't agree on this issue so I'll return to under my bridge.

Comment: @DuncanJones The fact of the matter is that the method does throw `EOFException` at end of stream. I don't see what isn't convincing about that. It shares this property with most of the methods of `DataInput`, which it extends. There's no room for debate about it. The fact also remains that it isn't necessarily convenient to collect all the objects being written prior to writing any of them.

Comment: An `EOFException` is also thrown if the stream data (i.e. the file) has been truncated, so how would you tell the difference in your design? Just because an API throws an exception doesn't mean the API designers expect you to use that to control behaviour.

Comment: @DuncanJones End of stream is still end of stream, whatever caused it. It's not 'my design', it's Java's design. You call readObject() at EOS: it throws EOFException. Period. There's nothing to discuss.

Comment: Keep an open mind, this is just a friendly discussion :-)  I say "your design" because you were advocating it as the best method of determining that you've finished reading objects. I suggest there is a better approach that would work in many cases. If my approach is used, the `EOFException` would indicates bad news (i.e. truncation of data). Note that your argument could be used to suggest catching an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is a reasonable way of determining a loop index has grown too large, because the API designers have chosen to throw it from `List.get()`.